# How to notify a user of a bad edit?

Tags: support, comments

If a bad edit is made to a question *(for instance revision 2 on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14359391/revisions))* what are the accepted guidelines? I left a comment on the question, @'ing the user but, I don't think they will receive a notification as they have not commented them self, correct?

Comment: For the record, such thing should be marked with `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags, not code block. (It still preserves formatting, just without syntax highlight)

Comment: You can directly link to revisions by the way, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14359391/2).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The comment is sufficient, editors get notified of `@comments`.

Answer (score -3):

we also can add one more option to the user's logo: for example email. by clicking that option, we can send notification to him or her

Comment: This seems excessive. Also, not everyone has an email account listed.